# Loop network request until criteria matched in results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use the GoCardless API to find out if an email address exists in a customer base.
What I'm trying to achieve is to pull the first set of 100 results, if check to see if the email in those results matches the email I'm checking. 
If it does, then return `true`.  If it doesn't, then it'll call the API again with the cursor given from the first set of results, and keep going until either it gets to the end or a result is found.

Once a result is found, it breaks the loops and returns true. If it gets to the end of the results and no match it found, it returns false.

I cant quite get the logic right below, and then I've also got the issue of having an await inside a loop.

```
const data = await client.customers.find({limit: 100});
const customers = data.customers;
let found = customers.some(c => c.email === data.email);

if (found) return true;

let cursor = data.meta.cursors.end;
let finished = false;

while (cursor || !finished) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
  const data = await client.customers.find({limit: 100, cursor});
  const f = customers.some(c => c.email === data.email);
  if (f) {
    finished = true;
    found = true;
  }
}

return finished && found;
```

Can anyone advise on how I can modify this to achieve the results I need?

Comment: According to the documentation for GoCardless, the `find` is for finding a single customer. You'll want to use the `list` instead. https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#customers-list-customers. You will be obtaining a cursor from call X, which should then be used in call X+1. https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#api-usage-cursor-pagination

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `list` instead of `find` and use the cursors (before/after) returned from one call on subsequent calls:

```
let after;
while(true) {
  let res = client.customers.list({limit: 100, after});
  if(res.resources.length === 0) {
    return false; // No more customers to look through
  }
  if(res.resources.some(c => c.email === theEmailYouAreLookingFor)) {
    return true;
  }
  after = res.cursors.after;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Their library also has a helper method that iterates through the pages for you! From [the readme](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-nodejs#the-all-method):

> All resources with a `list` method will also have an additional `*all` method. This method acts like the regular `list` method and accepts the same parameters, but instead returns an async generator.

At the time of writing, the implementation for `customers.all()` can be found [here](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-nodejs/blob/0ee1b90cd9bce27430b118328952c27934ddea9d/src/services/customerService.ts#L229-L242).

Something like this might work for your use case:

```js
for await (const customer of client.customers.all()) {
  if (customer.email === "hello@example.com") {
    console.log(`Found! ${customer.id}`);
    break;
  }
}
```